# How to change Android's Google Chrome's default downloader? (not under app - set default)

Tags: default-applications

I set Android's Google Chrome's default downloader to ES File Explorer and now I want to reset it back to Google Chrome. I found this to be impossible on Android 7.0 - I tried to uninstall both Chrome and ES File Explorer and then cleared all default application in app settings yet when I download a file ES File Explorer comes up. The only solution is to remove ES File Explorer from the system. Is there another way to fix this without reinstalling the OS or do a factory reset?

Comment: Try resetting all defaults using [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.anyro.picker). If that doesn't help uninstalling ES is perhaps the way out short of factory reset

Comment: @beeshyams I've tried this and it doesn't help. I just did a factory reset to fix it.

Comment: I guess I was a bit too late....You have to just disable ES downloader from settings within the app itself. Next time you open a download link it prompts again for a suitabele app and then you select the preferred handler.

Comment: I do agree with you that its kind of a bug where you can't clear defaults in settings → apps , as I mentioned in this related [post](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/188789/209414)...only "workaround" is to clear defaults from within ES app itself.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to first **disable** ES Downloader (download manager) from ES explorer settings:

- Open ES explorer and navigate to Settings → (Tools settings) → Download manager
- Tap on Download manager and check **Disable ES Downloader**
- Now open your preferred browser (Chrome) and open a downloadable link, it should now prompt you as before and select the suitable handler.
- Essentially you would've cleared the default handler for downloading links.

[image] [image]

Note: *I have also observed a similar bug in Android 7, where the defaults are not simply cleared the conventional way (i.e by going to Settings → Applications → Clear defaults, for now this is the better way to do it whenever ES explorer is involved.*

This may also depend on version of ES explorer in use. I tested with version 4.0.4.7

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall es explorer
2. Download anyfile with chrome (and then pop ups will let us choose what download manager will we choose, then select chrome always ask)
3. Reinstall your es explorer
4. Now your download manager back to original