How to open local file from Android HTML Viewer?
I am trying to make an html file that I can open with HTML Viewer and play a video stored locally on my phone. However, when I open the html with HTML Viewer I get this:

It shows the video player, but it does not show a video. However, it also doesn't display any errors.
This is my html file:
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="file:///storage/emulated/0/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>


Possible duplicate of Local files revisited: Opening local HTML files (file:///path/to/file) in Chrome on Android 10.x

@Robert I am not getting an access denied error, also the question (and answers) are specifically referencing Chrome.

So "HTML Viewer" is a third party app? If yes please add a link in your question to it's Play Store site. App names can be totally different for different localizations. The linked question is about using the file protocol for accessing local files in the shared storage of Android. This is exactly what you are asking for, too. Check logcat for error messages.

@Robert HTML Viewer is built into Android. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/188786/is-it-a-virus-htmlviewer

@KovyJacob Please identify your device make/model/OS version. I am unable to find 'HTML Viewer' on my Pixel 6a with Android 13. Checking logcat for details/errors is best.

@MorrisonChange It's Android 11, if I select an HTML file and open with, one of the options is HTML viewer.

@KovyJacob Please add details to your post about how you accessing the HTML file such as app name and steps on how you got the HTML file (download, editor, etc.). Do realize that different manufacturers may add in their own "File Manager" app so info make/model would be helpful.

I have a feeling the video player is shown because of the <video> tag, but it cannot access the file due to system restrictions. What happens if you put a random/invalid file location? Does it show the same?

@MorrisonChang I am accessing it with HTML Viewer, and Android system app.

@AndrewT. Ah good point... Do you know if there is a way to get it to show?
